# Селект с пагинацией без селекта всех записей

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть проект на laravel, в одном из методов по получению списка заявок я получаю общее кол-во заявок для пагинации и потом 20 из этого числа по смещению.
На проде кол-во заявок уже около  150к, время выполнения не самое радужное, около 3 секунд
У меня подозрения, что в момент фильтрации заявок Eloquent берет все записи, оттуда и долгое  ожидания
Если так, то есть ли способ не брать все заявки?
Код таков:

```
$filter = app()->make(OrderFilter::class, ['params' =>  ArrayHelper::filter($data)]);

    $query = Order::filter($filter)
        ->whereHas('client')
        ->where('something', '=', 1)
        ->orderBy($sort, $order);
    $count = $query->count();
    $query = $query->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit);
    // something
    return [/*data from $query*/];
```

Я смотрел решения с помощью чанков, но это не подходит, ибо данные после всех манипуляций летят на фронт, чанки тут бесполезны будут

Comment: Подозрения или факт? Сколько времени отрабатывает получение $count и сколько $query?

Comment: Индексы на полях по которым идет отбор есть? Какая версия laravel?

Comment: @evgen_dev, индексы есть, но не по всем полям, на все вешать не очень хочется, только на те, что больше всего используются, т.к. обновление индексов может больше потерь принести. но тут проблема в том, что долгое выполнение даже при первом посещении страницы, то есть без фильтров, кроме something поля, оно индексом покрыто. версия laravel 10

Comment: @intskull сложно оптимизировать запрос по коду билдера, не видя запроса и структуры таблиц, 150к строк это не так уж и много. Банально - ORDER BY может не слабо тормозить запрос.

Answer (score -1):

### Общие рекомендации

1. Полагаю, что для параметра "something" у модели Order необходимо добавить индекс в таблицу orders, и затем использовать этот параметр первым в запросе.
2. Долгим может быть именно запрос по по подсчету кол-ва заявок  в таблице, поскольку выполняется обход всех требуемых строк.
3. Для ускорения подобного мероприятия, можно попробовать переписать пагинацию по типу Cursor-пагинация - https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/pagination#cursor-paginaciia
   Для Cursor-пагинации используется несколько иной и более быстрый принцип выбора данных и формирования ссылок на страницы. Это подойдет в том случае, если ссылки на каждую страницу с заявками - не критичный функционал. То есть Cursor-пагинация даст ссылки только на следующую и предыдущую страницы.

Рекомендую использовать, как минимум, Debug-bar для Laravel, чтобы выяснить какой именно запрос выполняется долго, и затем оптимизировать.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем пункт 2 после пункта 1. Если добавить нужный индекс, то "обходить строки" никто не будет, количество будет получено прямиком из индекса. Другое дело, что индекса по something может быть недостаточно. В целом, курсорная пагинация тут будет смотреться как седло на корове - сложно, непонятно и бессмысленно. На будущее порекомендую воздерживаться от обобщенных рецептов, а давать советы для решения конкретных проблем.

Comment: Уважаемый, Вы комментарий с какой целью оставили? Кому именно от такого комментария стало лучше? Если имеется психологическая потребность демонстрировать свои знания и навыки - демонстрируйте качественным ответом на вопрос тому пользователю, который этот вопрос задал.

Comment: Не всегда следует торопиться демонстрировать свои навыки и знания впопыхах. Иногда стоит сначала уточнить детали вопроса.